# Search control on WP7/WP7.5

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

Could anyone tell me which controls are used in WP7 / WP7.5 where we go on e-mails reading, and when we click on the "search" button?

It appears on the top of a searchbox (a TextBox) and the middlle/bottom of the page is a little blurred. I need to code an application like this, and I don"t know which control to use.

Thanks a lot.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no one control that does the exact scenario you described.

You'll have to add a Textbox and a list for search on the bottom by yourself. Then, respond when the user hits the the "Enter" key, like so:

XAML:

```
<TextBox Name="textBox1" KeyDown="OnKeyDownHandler"/>
```

C#:

```
private void OnKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        //Search the data source you want
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks :) So, i don't need to create a new page ? I juste need to display the textblox, and the list "on" my page, and blurred the middle/bottom of the page?

Comment: You can do the search either on your page or a new one, But that page will have to contain the data source your searching on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TextBox and a list box to show the searched result. If you want you can use an image button to show search icon. You can use this button's click event to perform the search operation and can show the result in the listbox below.